# BigQuery - extract text and subtext

Tags: google-bigquery, text-extraction

I have a table in BigQuery about number of contracts sent out on day to day basis:

```
date        contract
2014-05-04  {jeans = 5, caps = 12, CDs = 1, Microwaves = 7, other = 6}
2014-05-05  {cups = 7, other = 5}
```

I need to filer out how many not classified contracts (=other) were sent out. By now I do it by downloading the CSV and figuring it out in Excel.

How could I get within BQ a table like this:

```
date        other_contracts
2014-05-04   6
2014-05-05   5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regexp_extract and look for the digits sequence...

```
SELECT
  *,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(contract,r'other = (\d+)') AS Other
FROM (
  SELECT
    "2014-05-04" AS Date,
    "{jeans = 5, caps = 12, CDs = 1, Microwaves = 7, other = 6}" AS contract),
  (
  SELECT
    "2014-05-05" AS Date,
    "{cups = 7, other = 5}" AS contract)
```

Answer (score 2):

More generic approach. 
Can be helpful I think:

```
SELECT 
  Date,
  INTEGER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Item, r'(\d+)')) AS Count,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(Item, r'(\w+)') AS Item
FROM (
  SELECT Date, SPLIT(contract) as Item
  FROM 
    (SELECT "2014-05-04" AS Date, "{jeans = 5, caps = 12, CDs = 1, Microwaves = 7, other = 6}" AS contract),
    (SELECT "2014-05-05" AS Date, "{cups = 7, other = 5}" AS contract)
)
ORDER BY Date, Count DESC
```

Result is:

```
Date    Count   Item
5/4/2014    12  caps
5/4/2014    7   Microwaves
5/4/2014    6   other
5/4/2014    5   jeans
5/4/2014    1   CDs
5/5/2014    7   cups
5/5/2014    5   other
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the format of data in the first table to JSON, then you can use https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=en#jsonfunctions